# Intercambiar contraseña con cifrado PBKDF2 por contraseña de texto plano en DJANGO

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

¿Existe alguna forma de deshabilitar la forma en que se guarda la contraseña en Django?
Es decir guardar la contraseña en texto plano; por las siguientes razones:

1.- Cuando un usuario no recuerda la contraseña no es posible crear una nueva contraseña debido a que es necesario tener la contraseña angtigua para poder crear la nueva.

2.- No tengo formulario para registrar nuevo usuario, el registro lo hago desde el admin.

[image: Ejemplo de USER 1]

[image: Formulario para cambiar contraseña, pero es necesario saber la contraseña anterior para poder crear la nueva]

[image: La contraseÑa en la BDD]

Comment: Una humilde sugerencia, no quites esa seguridad, mejor crea una manera de resetear la clave del usuario, por ejemplo crea un script para que guarde como clave una clave cifrada que tu conozcas

Comment: Almacenar contraseñas en texto plano es sumamente inseguro y está completamente desaconsejado. Sería poco ético explicarte como hacer eso. Sugiero que crees dos nuevas preguntas: "Cómo puedo crear un formulario de registro de usuarios con Django?" y "Cómo permitir que los usuarios recuperen una contraseña olvidada?"

Comment: @YoAlbert no es una buena idea lo que estas aconsejando. Es una muy mala práctica de seguridad.

Comment: @PanchoJay me podrías enviar esa documentación ?

Comment: @PanchoJay Entiendo que sea  por seguridad etc; sin embargo la aplicación que estoy implementando es pequeña y no requiere que tenga esa configuración.